# Magento 2 nginx restricting admin are by IP address not working

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish

I am trying to restrict access to the admin area by IP address, but it's not working. When I type in the admin url, it redirects me to the home page. If I change the IP address being whitelisted, it comes up with a `403 forbidden` message. Here is my current whitelist configuration for Nginx:

```
   location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {
     allow 67.166.183.12;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
deny all;

   }
```

Everything I have seen online says to use this configuration for whitelisting the admin page for Magento 2. If I don't have the whitelist active, I can access the admin page. My site uses Nginx and Varnish for caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [IP whitelisting for Magento 2 admin area](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento-2/whitelist-ip-addresses-for-magento-2-admin-protection) using NGINX by allocating a separate `location`, and unconditionally route requests through `index.php`.

Citing the article linked:

```
location ~ "^/admin_" {

    allow 1.2.3.4;
    allow 1.2.3.5;
    allow 1.2.3.6;
    deny all;

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=4G \n max_execution_time=600 \n max_input_vars=100000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

> Since all requests to admin area will unconditionally go through PHP-FPM, we have eliminated try_files, and by this made things faster in terms of accessing admin area.
> The extra benefit of allocating this block, is of course, the one we want – being able to apply additional configuration

Needless to say, you will need to adjust value to `fastcgi_pass` to point to your actual PHP-FPM socket.